# jQuery resize all images with a certain class to be square

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My page content is dynamically created, I am trying to write a script that searches for all images in a container 'image-rounded', and if they are not square, change either the height or width to make them square (based on the size of the smallest edge).

Here is my script so far:

```
jQuery(function($) { 
  $('.wrapper-site').find('.image-rounded img').each(function () { 
    var round_image_width = $(this).width();
    var round_image_height = $(this).height();

if(round_image_height > round_image_width) {
  $(this).css('height', 'round_image_width');
} else {
  $(this).css('width', 'round_image_height');
}

  });  
});
```

But currently this does nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(this).css('height', 'round_image_width');
```

should be

```
$(this).css('height', round_image_width);
```

Same for the height... Happens to the best of us :)

Comment: `+'px'` will be needed as well!